# ¿Cómo validar si un div está vacío o lleno con jquery o js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Necesito saber si es posible saber si un `div` está vacío o lleno para saber si le puedo imprimir datos dentro de él o no puedo imprimir código**. ¿Cuál sería el código, más o menos? Actualmente he probado con el siguiente código:

En el ***html*** tengo lo siguiente:

```
<div class="form-check mx-1">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="validarSI#1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
       Si
    </label>
</div>
<div id="inprimirSi#1"></div>
```

y en el ***script*** tengo lo siguiente:

```
const check = document.getElementById('validarSI#1')
check.addEventListener('click', (checked) => {
    let notes = document.getElementById('inprimirSi#1')
    for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i].innerHTML == "") {
            console.log('Hola mundo');
        }
    }
    if ($("#inprimirSi#1").html() == "") {
        notes.innerHTML += `
        <div class="form-floating mb-3 col-12 col-md-3 mx-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="compañiaseguro" placeholder="">
            <label for="compañiaseguro">compañia Aseguradora</label>
        </div>
        `
    }
})
```

el cual hace lo siguiente: primero con el **checkbox** le da a si se ejecuta un evento de click, después mira si el ***div está vacío***, y si lo está, imprime la información **con innerHTML**.
He probado con js y jquery pero no me ha funcionado. ¿Qué puedo hacer para que saber si el div está vacío o lleno? Esto lo hago para solo imprimir una vez nada más la información que necesito.

Comment: El selector de ID `inprimirSi#1` es incorrecto, no debes incluir caracteres especiales, elimina el `#` o cámbialo por guion o guion bajo, con eso debería funcionar. Por otra parte, no es recomendable mezclar Javascript puro con jQuery, complica la lectura y mantenimiento del script.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para poner tu código actualizado.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda la solucion fue efectiva @Triby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El selector de ID **inprimirSi#1** es incorrecto, no debes incluir caracteres especiales, elimina el **#** o cámbialo por guion o guion bajo, con eso debería funcionar. gracias por la solucion a mi problema a ***@Triby*** el codigo jquery queda de la siguiente manera :

```
const check = document.getElementById('validarSI_N1')
                            check.addEventListener('click', (checked) => {
                                let notes = document.getElementById('inprimirSi_N1')
                                
                                if ($("#inprimirSi_N1").html() == "") {
                                    notes.innerHTML += `
                                    <div class="form-floating mb-3 col-12 col-md-3 mx-1">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="compañiaseguro" placeholder="">
                                        <label for="compañiaseguro">compañia Aseguradora</label>
                                    </div>
                                    `
                                }
                            })
```

espero que les sea util a las personas que tienen la misma duda